# Is it possible to use Google Cloud to host a Wikipedia-like website (Wikimedia open source code)?

Tags: cloud-hosting, google-cloud, wikipedia

I am wanting to create a small Website similar to Wikipedia that uses Wikimedia open source code. I plan on hosting it on free Google Cloud platform, and then use freenom.com to obtain a free domain name. However, it is said that Wikipedia-like websites are dynamic, while free Google Cloud can only host static websites.

So I would like to ask that, is it possible to use Google Cloud to host a Wikipedia-like website ?

Comment: Where did you hear that Google Cloud can only host static websites?  That just isn't true.   There may be storage options in Google Cloud that are best used with static content, but they also offer virtual machines that you can use like any webserver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to host a Wikipedia-like website on Google Cloud.

You will want to use [Google Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/). Install [MediaWiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki) if you want a Wikipedia-like wiki, or a different piece of wiki software if you want a wiki that functions less like Wikipedia but that is easier to configure.

Comment: Maximillian Laumeister --- Thank you. I have never used Google Computer Engine before, but I will search more about it.

Comment: @Zhetdudf, do you feel that I answered your question completely? If so, please don’t forget to mark my answer as "accepted" by clicking the gray checkmark to the left of the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Ok. I just did so